# scala: using function definitions

Tags: scala, math

In the code below, the first function *compiles*. The second *doesn't* compile.

```
type FTDoubleDouble_Double = (Double, Double) => Double
val _dividedBy: FTDoubleDouble_Double =
{
    _ / _.toDouble
}
val _dividedByThenLog: FTDoubleDouble_Double =
{
    val result1 =  _ / _.toDouble
    scala.math.log(result1)
}
```

The compilation error is

> `cannot resolve symbol /`

I am sure this is basic, but I am a bit confused.

Comment: can you please look into this:https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 1st case the type ascription helps the compiler figure out what the underscores are supposed to represent: 2 `Double` values. (Which makes the `.toDouble` cast redundant and pointless.)

The 2nd case doesn't compile because there aren't enough hints to help the compiler.

You can fix that...

```
val result1 :FTDoubleDouble_Double =  _ / _
```

...but then you've got another problem.

```
scala.math.log(result1)  //error
```

`math.log()` takes a `Double` as the passed-in parameter, which you don't have.

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
val _dividedByThenLog: FTDoubleDouble_Double =
  (d1 :Double, d2 :Double) => scala.math.log(d1 / d2)
```

Comment: thanks...and yes, the toDouble is redundant. I guess I must have had an Int argument originally and forgot to delete when I changed to Double